# Fresh install of lubuntu synaptic is missing the search box in the tool bar

Tags: lubuntu, synaptic

A complete new install of **lubuntu 11.10** [...**17.10**] has **synaptic 0.75.2ubuntu7**  [...**0.84.2**]. Previously when using synaptic on another system there was a **search box** in the tool bar where a search string could be entered which would reduce the displayed packages as the string was being entered. The box is not being displayed nor do I find any setting to enable/disable it.

Comment: this is still a bug in 12.10 Lubuntu however solved with the answer provided

Comment: experienced in lubuntu 15.10, fixed with provided answer

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install apt-xapian-index
sudo update-apt-xapian-index -vf
```

From: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1178974

Comment: Unfortunately this solution does not work for me (ubuntu x64 12.10 fresh install)

Comment: works for ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Needed this in Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 as well.

Comment: What are these commands doing? What are we installing? Just giving the link is dangerous, as it might die. Would be nice to have an explanation.

Answer (score 9):

If the other answers don't help then try:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall synaptic
sudo dpkg-reconfigure synaptic
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

[forums linuxmint](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=141&t=70350) suggests installing **apt-xapian-index** when the box is present but grayed out. This solution also works in this case where the **Quick Filter** box is completely missing.